# how to perform a table join when the other table has many rows corresponding to one row in mother table

Tags: mysql

I have two table --> `tbl_book_details and tbl_table_traking`

```
tbl_book_details has columns bd_book_code,
  bd_isbn,
  bd_title,
  bd_edition,
  bd_author,
  bd_publisher,
  bd_supplier,
  bd_page,
  bd_price_type,
  bd_cost_price,
  bd_price,
  bd_Tax,
  bd_covering,
  bd_availability,
  bd_keywords,
  bd_notes,
  bd_details,
  bd_news_latter,
  bd_etDate,
  bd_weight,
  bd_expire_date,
  bd_status 



tbl_table_traking has columns 
 tt_id,
  tt_action,
  tt_table,
  tt_record_id,
  tt_on_date,
  tt_user,
  tt_status
```

the process is a trigger is defined on tbl_book_details which in case of insert/modify insert the data in tbl_table_traking for traking when and who has modified the records.

till now i have been using following query which is not a join -->

```
SELECT 
  tbl_books_details.bd_book_code AS bkid,
  tbl_books_details.bd_isbn,
  tbl_books_details.bd_title AS title,

  -- This part is what I believe is slowing down my query
  (SELECT 
    tt_on_date 
  FROM
    tbl_table_tracking 
  WHERE tt_action = 'MODIFY' 
    AND tt_record_id = tbl_books_details.bd_book_code ORDER BY tt_on_date) AS bd_etdate
```

it was working fine when the records count were below 3 million, but now script time out is occurring.

I have made the index on `tbl_table_traking` on '`tt_ondate`' and on `tt_action`,

If there any way i can convert it to a join or improve the performance?

the table traking query is returning the mostrecent date on which the record was modified.

my database is in mysql.

Comment: @Ranta...please format the code for beter understanding

Comment: It looks like you didn't include half of your query. Can you post the full query. Also, if you know you need a join why didn't you try that?

Comment: @JohnFx  I am not able to change the query to a join, therefore I have asked here

Comment: Here is some documentation on writing a query with a join: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this.

```
SELECT 
tbl_books_details.bd_book_code AS bkid,
tbl_books_details.bd_isbn,
tbl_books_details.bd_title AS title,
tbl_table_traking.tt_on_date
FROM
tbl_books_details
INNER JOIN tbl_table_tracking
tbl_books_details.bd_book_code = tbl_table_tracking.tt_record_id
WHERE tt_action = 'MODIFY';
```

Hope this helps...